# OpenCV 3.0 with Python 2.7.10 VideoCapture.read() returns old frame

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently using OpenCV 3.0 through its Python bindings in Windows.

Until a couple days ago, I was using OpenCV 2.4, which was distributed with the Python(x,y) distribution I installed.

With OpenCV 2.4, when I called `VideoCapture.read()`, the capture device captured an image and immediately returned it. It was wonderful.

In OpenCV 3.0, the behavior seems much stranger. As soon as I create the capture device, it seems to capture a frame. That frame is the first frame returned by `VideoCapture.read()`. The next call to `VideoCapture.read()` returns the image captured during the first call to `VideoCapture.read()`, and so on.

I've tried using `VideoCapture.grab()` and `VideoCapture.retrieve()` instead, but I see the same strange behavior. In fact, if I repeatedly call `VideoCapture.retrieve()` (without calling `grab()` or `read()`, I keep getting new frames.

I couldn't find anyone else having this issue, or any documentation of this behavior change.

I've tried building OpenCV 3.0 myself, and using the precompiled version that comes with the windows installer, and they have the same behavior. I was using the same webcam with both OpenCV 2.4 and OpenCV 3.0, so that can't be the issue either.

Is this the expected behavior with OpenCV 3.0? Is there a way to recover the 2.4 behavior without making two read requests every time I want to take a snapshot?

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Python2.7 and OpenCV3.0. Calling only `VideoCapture.retrieve()` seems to return incomplete frames and calling twice `VideoCapture.read()` still produces the wrong behavior. Did you find a better way to fix it?

Comment: @Ianlet I don't remember ever having solved that issue, but it was six months ago, so my memory is pretty fuzzy to begin with. I certainly don't know the solution off the top of my head, sorry :(